# Excluding unique values from an array in C

Tags: c

This code aims to exclude non-repeating values in a number list, but does not return repeats in their original sequence. How to keep all repeats with their precedence?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int count=0;
int main ()
{
int i,j,k,x, altarray[1000],array[1000];
printf("Please enter the number of integers in your list:\n");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf ("Please enter the list of numbers\n");
for (i=0; i<x; i++)
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
printf("\nThe corrected array is...\n");
for (i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    for (j=i+1; j<x; j++)
    {
        if(array[i]==array[j])
        {
            altarray[count]=array[i];
            count++;
        }

    }
}
for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    printf("%d",altarray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and narrowing down where the error could be? This would help you to ask a specific question([ask]) and not just "Why is my code not working?".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for duplicated number, you have to cover all elements of your array in the `j` `for` loop except the one that have the index `i`. So that loop should look like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
{
    if ((array[i] == array[j]) && (i != j))
    {
        altarray[count] = array[i];
        count++;
        break;
    }
}
```

I have added a `break`, to avoid wasting cycles after detecting the existence of the duplicated number.

Comment: If we are to be saving cycles, `i != j && array[i] == array[j]` would be better. One less comparison.

Comment: @DeiDei Yes, that would be better :).